# Getting Submit Button to Pick Up Text in Textarea

Tags: html, forms

I have a textarea that shows a random joke. I want the joke to post to Twitter using this link with the submit button: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=
but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the text that's been generated in the textarea to be picked up in the link. I know there's an easy way to make this happen, but nothing I've tried has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Here's the code I've got:

```
<form name="quoteForm">
  <textarea wrap="virtual" name="quoteHere" rows="6" cols="40">Your joke is loading... unless your JavaScript is disabled
  </textarea><br>  <input type=button value="Previous" onClick="prevQuote();">
  <input type=button value="Next" onClick="nextQuote();">
  <input type=button value="Random" onclick="randQuote();"><br>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Tweet This Joke"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute of `textarea` was changed from `quoteHere` to `text`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form name="quoteForm" action="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" onsubmit="submit();">
  <textarea wrap="virtual" name="text" rows="6" cols="40">Your joke is loading... unless your JavaScript is disabled
  </textarea><br>  <input type=button value="Previous" onClick="prevQuote();">
  <input type=button value="Next" onClick="nextQuote();">
  <input type=button value="Random" onclick="randQuote();"><br>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Tweet This Joke"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do I put the Javascript relative to the form? Thanks for your help.

Comment: inside script tags.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the data in the query string then you need to make a GET request (which you are already doing), not a POST request (which you say you want to do).

If you want to send the data to `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet` then you need to put that URL in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element. Since you have no `action` it will submit to the URL of *your current page* instead.

If you want the data to be associated with the query string parameter `text` then you need to name the textarea `text` and not, as you have, `quoteHere`.